# Spark GraphFrames High Shuffle read/write

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-graphx, graphframes

Hi I have created Graph using vertex and edge files. Size of graph is 600GB. I am querying this graph using motif feature of Spark GraphFrames.
I have setup an AWS EMR cluster for querying graph.

cluster details:- 1 master and 8 slaves

Master Node:

```
    m5.xlarge
    4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
    EBS Storage:64 GiB
```

Slave Node:

```
    m5.4xlarge
    16 vCore, 64 GiB memory, EBS only storage
    EBS Storage:256 GiB (per instance)
```

I am facing very high shuffle read(3.4TB) and write(2TB), this is affecting performance and it takes around 50 mins to execute only 10 queries.Is there any way to reduce such high shuffle.

Following is my spark code:-

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkGraph POC").getOrCreate()

val g:GraphFrame  = GraphFrame(vertexDf, edgeDf)

//queries

    val q1 = g.find(" (a)-[r1]->(b); (b)-[r2]->(c)")

    q1.filter(
      " r1.relationship = 'knows' and" +
                  " r2.relationship = 'knows'").distinct()
      .createOrReplaceTempView("q1table")

    spark.sql("select a.id as a_id,a.name as a_name," +
                      "b.id as b_id,b.name as b_name," +
                      "c.id as c_id,c.name as c_name from q1table")
      .write
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("header","true")
      .csv(resFilePath + "/q1")

    spark.catalog.uncacheTable("q1table")

    val q2 = g.find(" (a)-[r1]->(b); (b)-[r2]->(c); (c)-[r3]->(d); (d)-[r4]->(e)")
    q2.filter(
      " a.name = 'user1' and" +
        " e.name = 'user4' and" +
        " r1.relationship = 'knows' and" +
        " r2.relationship = 'knows' and" +
        " r3.relationship = 'knows' and" +
        " r4.relationship = 'knows'").distinct()
      .createOrReplaceTempView("q2table")

    spark.sql("select a.id as a_id, a.name as a_name ," +
      "e.id as e_id, e.name as e_name from q2table")
      .write
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("header","true")
      .csv(resFilePath + "/q2")

    spark.catalog.uncacheTable("q2table")

spark.stop()
```

[image]

Comment: Try to write vertexDf and edgeDf to disk partitioned by user and relationship. In my case with a similar scenario reduced the total time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the implementation of Graphframes is that it makes self joins of the internal dataframes as many times as you use on the motifs. That means that you will have more a more shuffle as the length of the chain increases

You can see more details at https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-graphframes/motifs-finding-graphframes/read

I have also tried a similar approach and have seen that when the length of the chain is greater than 12 Spark starts being not responsive and connections are lost with executors, even if I increased resources.

If you are trying to do that, I would recommend using a graph database instead.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Oscar Lopez M I tried using aws neptune graph db, but problem is that it is costly, also other cloud graph dbs like neo4j,titan,tiger-graph are also costly. Hence I am switching to spark graphframes since we can have gremlin like traversal queries using motif feature. But it seems graphframes are not scalable

Comment: I think we are on the same page Abhik. But I can also recommend other approaches like ArangoDB https://www.arangodb.com/ that even on the Enterprise Edition has a forever plan evaluation :).